# How can I check if there is a value in a MongoDB object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have my users in MongoDB that I identify with "nir" and "sN" my goal is to locate the user with nir 33 and sN 1234, once the user is located, see if "sR" has a "local" or "mobile" value, depending on whether it has the value "local" or "mobile" it sends to the console: isLocal: true, isMobile: false.

```
{nir: 33, sN: 1234 ,sR: "local"},
{nir: 33, sN: 4545 ,sR: "local"},
{nir: 81, sN: 2362 ,sR: "mobile"},
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do a find, and use the projection to wrangle the 2 flags.

```js
db.collection.find({
  // input your query here
  nir: 33,
  sN: 1234
},
{
  isLocal: {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        $ne: [
          {
            "$indexOfCP": [
              "$sR",
              "local"
            ]
          },
          -1
        ]
      },
      "then": true,
      "else": false
    }
  },
  isMobile: {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        $ne: [
          {
            "$indexOfCP": [
              "$sR",
              "mobile"
            ]
          },
          -1
        ]
      },
      "then": true,
      "else": false
    }
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wJvTjGen2pa) for your reference.